# What should the chat room be called?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

To make the chat room interesting both for visitors of Arduino.SE as well as other users within the Stack Exchange network, I think [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8489) should be renamed.

The (new) name should be something related to Arduino which any enthusiast would understand. It could be something esoteric or something based on popular culture.

This would help in attracting users from the Network to the room, as every time a new post is made, the room goes on the [active tab of Chat.SE](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=all&sort=active), where it may  get a fair bit of attention, if it looks interesting.

So, what should be the new name of the chat room?
Also, what should be the room description that goes with it?

<sub>*Copied from [my post on PP.SE](https://productivity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275)*</sub>

Answer (score 5):

### A couple I thought of off the top of my head:

> Pin 13

Pin 13 is a symbolic pin, mostly because it is the first pin ever used. You *did* want to be friendly to new users and attract them.

> `#define HIGH LOW`

Good luck debugging!!!

> digitalWrite(13, MEDIUM);

Who said that we had to have rules in the chat? :)

---

### Some bad ideas:

What we *shouldn't* do.

> Hacker's __

Arduino users are more than *hackers only*. We are artists, designers, hackers, hobbyists (like me!), and more.

---

If this post didn't help, **at least we established that I should *not* be put in charge of naming anything.** However, the point about "hacker" in the name (or any other name that suggests geekyness) should be avoided at all costs is pretty important. Sure *we* are geeks, but the whole Arduino community is a lot more.

Comment: I kinda like pin 13

Comment: I think 'Blink!' sounds nice as well.

Comment: You should make these separate posts so we can vote on them!

Comment: @AsheeshR If we call it Blink, people might think we're a Doctor Who fan group. :) (Not that there's anything wrong with that!)

Comment: I have chat admin for that room so I renamed it `Pin 13` and made the description a little better.

Answer (score 1):

How about something named after the Serial library? E.g.:

```
Serial.begin
```

Putting it without the parameter list seems a little nicer.

Or something a little more on-the-nose:

```
Serial.print("chat");
```

It's the kind of thing that any Arduino user is likely to recognise, but it's also not totally alien to anybody else who's done any programming. Admittedly, it's maybe less likely to hook EE folks though.

Comment: How about `Serial.begin(chat)`?